# Object of type decimal is not JSON serializable error in Django

Tags: python, django

I am following 'Django 2 by Example' book to create a ecommerce website in Django. But I am getting 'Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable' when I am trying to save order id in the request.session in the following line.

```
    request.session['order_id'] = order.id

    def order_create(request):
cart = Cart(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save()
        for item in cart:
            OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=order, product=item['product'], price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity'])

        # cart.clear()
        order_created.delay(order.id)

        request.session['order_id'] = order.id

        return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))
else:
    form = OrderCreateForm()

return render(request, 'orders/order/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we followed along the same tutorial as your views look a lot like mine. If that's the case then the problem is likely to be in the `cart.py` file. Try to get rid of your decimal functions in it. This might not be the best solution but that's how I solved this issue.